# Centering an Image in a Column - Bootstrap 4

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4, centering

This is a question I seem to always struggle with and I haven't really found an easy answer to. I just want to center an image or any other block element inside the Bootstrap Grid. Margin: auto seldom seems to work for me.

```
<!-- Services Section -->
    <div class ="container" id="services">
        <h2>My Service</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="img/wordpress.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="img/js.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="img/rails64.png">
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container services -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, it will center horizontally and vertically any element.

```
.centerImage{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Apply this class to the image which you can center agaisnt its parent.

Hoping it help.